# Building tabular report in Pandas with index aligned concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames that I want to merge or concat to build a report.

```
>>> df1
  class item  value
0     A   _1     10
1     A   _2     11
2     B   _3     12
3     X   _4     13
>>> df2
  class item  value
0     A   _5     20
1     B   _6     21
2     B   _7     22
3     C   _8     23
```

My target is to align these two DataFrames by "class" so that users can inspect items for each class. That is, the "class A" items are aligned and the first "class A" row contains the first item in "class A" from each DataFrame. The second "class A" row only contains an `item_1` as `df2` did not contain a second "class A" item.

```
>>> result
  class   item_1  value_1  item_2  value_2
0     A       _1       10      _5       20
1     A       _2       11     NaN      NaN
2     B       _3       12      _6       21
3     B      NaN      NaN      _7       22
4     C      NaN      NaN      _8       23
5     X       _4       13     NaN      NaN
```

I'd normally pass this off as "a presentation issue" and not really relevant to Pandas, but with streamlit I'm simply rendering the DataFrame on the page so it needs to be structured correctly.

This isn't a merge, nor a concat - it's almost like a partial merge (joining on the "class" column) followed by a concat operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

use `merge` with `cumcount`

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, how='outer', 
                 left_on=['class', df1.groupby('class').cumcount()], 
                 right_on=['class', df2.groupby('class').cumcount()], 
                 suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
          .sort_values('class').drop('key_1', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
```

out:

```
  class item_1  value_1 item_2  value_2
0     A     _1     10.0     _5     20.0
1     A     _2     11.0    NaN      NaN
2     B     _3     12.0     _6     21.0
3     B    NaN      NaN     _7     22.0
4     C    NaN      NaN     _8     23.0
5     X     _4     13.0    NaN      NaN
```

---

**Example Code**

df1 & df2

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'X'],
         'item': ['_1', '_2', '_3', '_4'],
         'value': [10, 11, 12, 13]}
data2 = {'class': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
         'item': ['_5', '_6', '_7', '_8'],
         'value': [20, 21, 22, 23]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: This is a great answer; a very clever use of `cumcount` to build an additional join key. Thank you!